# How do I export files from a Sharepoint list and subsite list using CSOM in a console?

Tags: 2013, list, csom

I need to create an application that exports files from SharePoint (from lists in the site and subsites). I'm planning to create a console application in Visual Studio and use CSOM. I've tried the code solutions in the following links:

[Cannot contact site at the specified URL on try ClientContext.ExecuteQuery();](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/168175/cannot-contact-site-at-the-specified-url-on-try-clientcontext-executequery/168203#168203)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17057074/how-to-download-upload-files-from-to-sharepoint-2013-using-csom

but unfortunately, I always get red underlined words in these codes, and I don't know what's wrong or what I'm missing. Can someone help me?

Comment: Do you import the library to use these classes or methods?

Comment: Tarek, thanks for you reply. Yes, I had imported the libraries. Nonetheless, after searching all these days, I ended up managing to do what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete code:

```
class Program
{
    static string url = "SiteURL";
    static string startPath = "Directory to the folder/devise where you want to save";

    static void Main()
    {
        getFiles(url); //saves the files into the desired folder
        Console.WriteLine("\nPress enter to close...");
        Console.Read();
    }

    public static void getFiles(string url)
    {
        try
        {
            ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(new Uri(@url));

            List List = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("ListName");
            ctx.Load(List);
            ctx.Load(List.RootFolder);
            ctx.Load(List.RootFolder.Folders);
            ctx.Load(List.RootFolder.Files);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();

            FolderCollection fcol = List.RootFolder.Folders;
            foreach (Folder f in fcol)
            {
                ctx.Load(f.Files);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                FileCollection fileCol = f.Files;
                foreach (File fileItem in fileCol)
                {
                    //gets the full directory (startpath + directory inside sharepoint)
                    var targetPath = startPath + System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(fileItem.ServerRelativeUrl);

                    if (!Directory.Exists(targetPath))
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
                    }

                    //To download files/items inside list folders
                    CopyFiles(fileItem, targetPath, url); 
                }
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private static void CopyFiles(File fileItem, string path, string url)
    {
        try
        {
            ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(new Uri(@url));
            var fileRef = fileItem.ServerRelativeUrl;
            Console.WriteLine(fileRef);
            var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileRef);
            var fileInfo = File.OpenBinaryDirect(ctx, fileRef);
            var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, fileName);
            var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(filePath);
            fileInfo.Stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
            fileStream.Close();
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```